# Why doesn't this Swift code type-check?

Tags: swift, generics, type-inference

The following Swift code:

```
class Workflow<ItemClass: Hashable> {
    var block: (ItemClass -> Int)?
    init() {}
}

protocol ProtocolX {
    typealias ItemClass
    func foo(x: ItemClass) -> Int
}

func test<Y: ProtocolX, ItemClass: Hashable>(protX: Y, x: ItemClass) {
    let workflow = Workflow<ItemClass>()
    workflow.block = { (x: ItemClass) in
        return protX.foo(x)
    }
}
```

fails with this compiler error:

```
Cannot invoke 'foo' with an argument list of type '(ItemClass)': 
Expected an argument list of type '(Self.ItemClass)'
```

in the code snippet `return protX.foo(x)`.

This may seem like a contrived example, but it's reduced from a real-world problem I'm having.

If I try following the advice in the error message, I just get:

```
'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class; 
did you mean 'Test'?
```

How can I get this to type-check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the compiler no reason to believe that `Workflow.ItemClass` is the same type as `ProtocolX.ItemClass` within function `test(_:x:)`. If you mean to require that the `ItemClass` type parameter to the `test` function be the same as `ProtocolX.ItemClass` within the function, you can tell the compiler to require it, like this:

```
func test<Y: ProtocolX, ItemClass: Hashable where Y.ItemClass == ItemClass>(protX: Y, x: ItemClass) {
    let workflow = Workflow<ItemClass>()
    workflow.block = { (x: ItemClass) in
        return protX.foo(x)
    }
}
```

But then you can eliminate the separate `ItemClass` parameter entirely:

```
func test<Y: ProtocolX where Y.ItemClass: Hashable>(protX: Y, x: Y.ItemClass) {
    let workflow = Workflow<Y.ItemClass>()
    workflow.block = { (x: Y.ItemClass) in
        return protX.foo(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the helpful and extremely quick answer!